# Why new line is added to variable at end?

Tags: bash, variables

**file.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
fileName="Screenshot_$(TZ=GMT-3 date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S).png"
echo "|$fileName|"
```

Terminal at Ubuntu 19.04:

```
> bash file.sh
|Screenshot_20190521_104141.png
|
```

I want to understand why a new-line is added to the variable at end?

Comment: Your `filename` variable _most_ likely contains a DOS CRLF instead of Unix's LF alone. You can easily recreate this by something like `fileName=$'AnyName.png\r\n'`

Comment: Remove it as `"${fileName//$'\r\n'/}"`

Comment: You are probably working on a DOS editor like Notepad++, which default encodes CRLF endings. Either change the setting to use Unix style endings or clean up the script by running `dos2unix <scriptname>`

Comment: @Inian Thanks, works! Didn't know about that